# Sass/CSS folding triangles in hexagon

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create a folding effect in a hexagon composed of triangles. So far I've only managed to make the triangles translate instead of folding over. I want to make

this http://jsfiddle.net/zn6jbhr6/

Relevant SCSS

```
@mixin hexTranslateKeyFrames($name, $degree) {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}

$hex-degree: 0deg;
@for $idx from 1 through 6 {
  $hex-degree: $hex-degree + 60;

  @include hexTranslateKeyFrames(hexTranslate#{$idx}, $hex-degree) {
    0% { transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotate($hex-degree); }
    54.55%, 100% { transform: rotateZ(360deg) rotate($hex-degree); }
  }
}

$order2: (0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, 0.6s, 0.8s, 1s);
.folding-hex {
  @include hexagon();

  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    .triangle:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: hexTranslate#{$i} 2.2s infinite #{nth($order2, $i)} linear;
    }
  }
}
```

more like this http://jsfiddle.net/wvm15yL4/

Relevant CSS

```
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1); 
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
          animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
          animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s; 
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
          animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  } 25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1; 
  } 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  } 
}

@keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  } 25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1; 
  } 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an animation that rotates in 3D.

Since it is a little hard, I have done it only once, and reused it for the other elements setting an intermediate element in the DOM that does the rotation in the plane

The first 2 parameters in the rotate3D are sin(60deg) and cos(60deg), to make the rotation axis be at 60 deg

```css
@keyframes flip {
   0%       { transform: rotate3d( 0.5, 0.866, 0,  90deg); 
              opacity: 0;}
   0.1%     { transform: rotate3d( 0.5, 0.866, 0,  90deg); 
              opacity: 1;}
  14%       { transform: rotate3d( 0.5, 0.866, 0,   0deg); }
  50%       { transform: rotate3d(-0.5, 0.866, 0,   0deg); }
  63.99%    { transform: rotate3d(-0.5, 0.866, 0, -90deg); 
              opacity: 1;}
  64%, 100% { transform: rotate3d(-0.5, 0.866, 0, -90deg); 
              opacity: 0}
}

.folding-hex {
  height: 69.28px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateX(40px) rotate(30deg); }

.rotator {
    transform-origin: 20px 37.64px;

}
.rotator:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(60deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(120deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotate(240deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotate(300deg); 
}
  
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 34.64px 20px 0;
    transform-origin: 20px 37.64px;
    border-color: #E50C4E transparent; 
    animation: flip 3s linear infinite;
}

.rotator:nth-child(2) .triangle {
    border-color: #b5093d transparent; 
    animation-delay: -2.5s;
}
.rotator:nth-child(3) .triangle {
    border-color: #b5093d transparent; 
    animation-delay: -2.0s;
}
.rotator:nth-child(4) .triangle {
    animation-delay: -1.5s;
}

.rotator:nth-child(5) .triangle {
    border-color: #f8799f transparent; 
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
}
.rotator:nth-child(6) .triangle {
    border-color: #f8799f transparent; 
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="folding-hex">
  <div class="rotator">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotator">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotator">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotator">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotator">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotator">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems for some triangles when they fold over, there's a thin line left behind. Maybe it's just a browser issue. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: I have added an opacity and some extra frames, now it should be ok in any browser. At 90deg, they shouldn't be visibles, but there must be some precision loss in some cases